# Configure selenium webdriver in docker container

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile

I have the following code:

```
fox = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

try:
    fox.get(url+search+id)
    image = BytesIO(fox.find_element_by_tag_name('table').screenshot_as_png)
    image.name = id + '.png'
except:
    fox.close()

fox.close()

return image
```

Its perfectly just works in windows 10 with env, but this code is just a part of one project, and i use docker to deploy it. The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

All i have after execution of the python code above is:

```
====== WebDriver manager ====== 
Current firefox version is 91.5 
Get LATEST geckodriver version for 91.5 firefox 
Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.30.0/geckodriver] found in cache
```

Comment: Can you please give a definition as precise as possible of ["it's just not working at all"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)? Thanks.

Comment: _But its just not working at all_: What error do you see?

Comment: With firefox installed I have the following output:
`====== WebDriver manager ======
Current firefox version is 91.5
Get LATEST geckodriver version for 91.5 firefox
Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/linux64/v0.30.0/geckodriver] found in cache`
Without, its just this message without firefox\geckodriver versions

Comment: Please do not put necessary information to answer your question in comments: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70943061/edit) your question.

Comment: @Zeitounator, did exactly what you wanted. Any solutions now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it work with this configuration:

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
fox = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=opts)
```

Also added this line to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install firefox-esr -y
```